# How to pass environment variables via Travis CI into the docker build commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile, travis-ci

I want to pass environment variables into the build commands both in before_install & after_success blocks. Below is the .travis.yml file.

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 12.13.0
service:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t ******/react-test -f ./frontend/Dockerfile.dev ./frontend

script:
  - docker run -e CI=true ******/react-test npm run test

after_success:
  - docker build -t ******/video-chat-client ./frontend
  - docker build -t ******/video-chat-nginx ./nginx
  - docker build -t ******/video-chat-api ./backend

  # Log in to the docker-cli
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin

  # Push the production images to docker-hub
  - docker push ******/video-chat-client
  - docker push ******/video-chat-nginx
  - docker push ******/video-chat-api
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Environment Variables` section, in the settings of your project in travis-ci web console. In my projects, I have added some variables there, and then used them in the `.travis.yml` file.

[image]